# Ternary operator in print statement of java

Tags: java, conditional-operator

Consider the below code snippet using ternary operator in print statement

```java
public static void main(){
    char a='A';
    int i=0;
    System.out.println(true?a:0);
    System.out.println(false?i:a);
}
```

The output of the above snipped is:

```
A 
65
```

Why is the output not as below:

```
A
A
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ternary operator with different types of expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50839244/ternary-operator-with-different-types-of-expressions)

Comment: 65 happens to be the ASCII (byte) code for `'A'`. The ternary operator yields a common type,`int`.

Comment: The conversion is clearly mentioned in the docs
   https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#:~:text=The%20type%20of%20a%20conditional%20expression,of%20the%20conditional%20expression%20is%20T.

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek yes 65 is ASCII code for 'A'. If its common state then even the first print should be printing 65 right.

Comment: @prajwaldcunha No. `System.out.println(true?a:i);` would be printing 65. But a literal `0` is not the same thing as `i`.